# How can i achieve req id for tracing using springboot microservices?

Tags: java, spring-boot

The ask is:

Whenever a client calls API's, i want to tag it with a unique identifier or use one supplied by the client (usually in a query param) and pass it across components until that request is fulfilled sucessfully or fails. The goal is to get a holistic picture of how a request was handled by different components and what happened at each component and quickly identify issues.

How can i achieve this using springboot microservices. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Cloud Sleuth is what you are looking for: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/

Spring Cloud Sleuth’s solution is to inject span and trace IDs into log entries. A trace ID is a unique identifier that an entire request flow will share. IA span is more local and is defined for each request received for each request sent event. They define particular interaction points.

The initial span, or root span, is generated when a client request is received from outside the distributed system. This request lacks trace and span information. The root span becomes the trace ID for the rest of the request flow through the system / systems.

The diagram below shows how Sleuth span and trace generation would work through a hypothetical service network.

[image]

All you need to do in your code is to add the dependency `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` and Spring will automatically instrument the following communication channels:

- requests over messaging technologies like Apache Kafka or RabbitMQ
- HTTP headers received at Spring MVC controllers
- requests made with the RestTemplate

Comment: This is "link only answer". Can you extend your answer, because links have tendency to rot.

Comment: Additional details added.

Comment: This looks overkill to me for getting a request id

Comment: The purpose of Sleuth is exactly to tackle use cases like the ones described in the answer, especially "The goal is to get a holistic picture of how a request was handled by different components and what happened at each component and quickly identify issues.". With Sleuth it is very easy to then use Zipkin for example for distributed tracing analysis. You could build your own solution, but what is more overkill: build and maintain your own solution that might not even work correctly, or use a battle-tested Spring feature by simply adding a dependency that does exactly what you seek?

Comment: Hi @JoãoDias - Thanks for your answer.

We need to use a generator utility for generating request_id. Also propagate request_id through out the execution path for tracing purpose. Create a common base class that has tracing enabled. How can i achieve this ?

Comment: That is exactly what Spring Cloud Sleuth provides you by taking advantage of the Tracer library named Brave. It works as depicted in the image above. If you need something custom I am not sure if Spring Cloud Sleuth can help (to be honest I've never tried that).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start simple you could define a filter (e.g. by extending [`OncePerRequestFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html)) that generates/extracts a request ID. You can also put it into Logback's [MDC](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html) so that it is included in every logging statement that is issued from the thread executing the request (if configured):

```java
@Component
public class RequestIdFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final ThreadLocal<String> requestId = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public Optional<String> getCurrentRequestId() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(requestId.get());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            requestId.set(UUID.randomUUID().toString()); // or extract from request
            MDC.put("requestId", requestId.get());
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            requestId.remove();
        }
    }
}
```